# Params not being sent with jquery-file-upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-file-upload

For some reason, I am getting the following error with my query-file-upload ajax form:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: profile):
    app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:146:in `profile_params'
    app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:52:in `create'
```

Here are the params that are sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fdsahKJAHLSJFJAHFAS323FDSGF4="}
```

So for some reason the profile params are not being sent.  Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @profile, :html => { :class => "clearfix", :id => "the_form"},
    remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :pic, name: 'profile[pic]', :class => "field file-field",
    :id => "file", :multiple => true %>
<% end %>
```

Here are my strong parameters:

```
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:title, :pic, :category, :description,
    :state, :zip_code, :rate)   
end
```

And here is the profiles#new action that loads the form:

```
def new
    @profile = Profile.new
@skills = Skill.all.collect {|skill| skill.label} #this is for something else on the page
end
```

Also, here is the coffee script file that gets the form.  Since the form is rendered via ajax, I need to use the ajaxcomplete method.

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).ajaxComplete ->
    $('#the_form').fileupload
      dataType: "script"
      add: (e, data) ->
        types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        file = data.files[0]
        if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
          data.submit()
        else
          alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")
      done: (e, data) ->
        $('#finish-text').html "Upload finished"
```

I know the coffee script works because it is working with another form.

Why aren't the profile params being sent?

Answer (score 2):

Add **:multipart => true** in your form as you have file upload field in your form

For ex:

```
 <%= form_for @profile, :html => { :class => "clearfix", :id => "the_form", :multipart => true}, remote: true do |f| %>
```